# Ctrl+Alt+F2 doesn't switch TTYs on laptop

Tags: tty

I'm unable to switch ttys using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>; nothing happens. Is there some other way to switch? Is there a problem with the keymapping? And how do I fix that? I'm on a US Lenovo X1 Carbon if that would be of any help.

Comment: Which distribution? Which login manager?

Comment: Debian with lightdm. However I realized that Fn-F[N] maps to F[N], so problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one has to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F[N]</kbd>

Comment: Sounds like this is specific to Lenovo's "adaptive keyboard" thing, from what I can find